# Is it possible to revert to CPU rendering if client's GPU is not up to spec?

Tags: flash

I'd like to be able to disable the GPU rendering in flash, if a user's computer doesn't have a good graphics card.
Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible only in AIR (you can choose rendering mode in it), you can't do it in flash.

BTW, I don't think, you'll get any advantage on PC, giving rendering task to CPU instead of GPU, if you consider user's videocard too weak. Nowadays the weakest videocards are netbooks' ones, they are really rather slow, but these PC's CPUs are not better.

Comment: We actually have some users with really good CPU and lots of RAM but very very poor graphics cards.